# How to split a raster into x tiles that overlapped by x km?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, tiles, splitting

I have a raster that I split into three tiles by using the function `Split raster` in ArcMap as follows:

[image]

How can I split my raster into three tiles that overlap by 2 km as follows : ?

[image]

Comment: So just to clarify - you still have 9 rasters in the second output, but they just overlap on the x axis by 2km?

Comment: Thank you very much GIS-Jonathan for your answer. Exactly, I still have 9 rasters in the second output that overlap on the x axis by 2km.

Comment: You can specify the overlap area in the split raster tool.  Have you tried this?  If so, what did not work?

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron for your answer. Yes, I specify in `Options` `Overlap (optional) = 2` and `Units for Output Raster Size and Overlap (optional) = kilometers` but it doesn't work. I obtain 9 rasters that don't overlap (as in my first figure).